# Hive Function for filtering credit card

Tags: sql, hive

Can anyone explainn the below code I am not able to understand

```
SELECT li.user_id 
FROM loan_info li 
     INNER JOIN credit_card_info cci ON li.user_id = cci.user_id 
WHERE CAST(cci.outstanding_balance AS double) = 0.0 
  AND datediff(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), li.last_payment_date) >= 30;

SELECT li.user_id 
FROM loan_info li INNER JOIN credit_card_info cci ON li.user_id = cci.user_id 
WHERE CAST(cci.outstanding_balance AS double) = 0.0 
  AND datediff(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), li.last_payment_date) >= 30;
```

Answer (score 1):

This filter means last payment was 30 or more days before current date:

```
datediff(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), li.last_payment_date) >= 30
```

Better use `current_date` instead of this: `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')`:

```
datediff(current_date, li.last_payment_date) >= 30
```

It does the same more efficiently because current_date constant fixed for the scope of query. And [unix_timestamp()](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#Date+Functions) is calculated for every row. See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56450811/2700344